# What makes a line "straight"?

Tags: geometry, definition

In Euclidean space, there can be several definitions that makes a straght line:

1. Line of shortest distance between two points
2. Line that is linear, i.e with the points satisfying a linear equation
3. Line of zero curvature everywhere
4. Line with constant curvature that is equal from both sides

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_%28geometry%29) states:

> In geometry, it is frequently the case that the concept of line is taken as a primitive.

When one enters non-Euclidean geometry, are the above definitions consistent with each other? Definition 1, for example, becomes a geodesic.

Comment: in differential geometry def. 1 is geodesic but def.2,def.3 define the straight line.

Comment: "linear equation" presupposes coordinates, which you may not necessarily have in nonEuclidean geometry.

Comment: Similarly, curvature entails a notion of limits, which doesn't make sense in, say, finite projective geometries. So 3 and 4 don't generalize terrible well either. And condition 1 requires a notion of distance, which also doesn't apply in finite projective geometries, like the 7-point projective plane.

Comment: So, there does not exist a single definition that is applicable to everywhere? (Or, almost everywhere?)

Comment: Firstly, the quote from Wikipedia is for "line" only. "Taken as a primitive" means that there is no attempt to define it. Adding "straight" starts a whole new ball game. To differentiate types of lines from each other by shape, you need something like coordinates and distance. Otherwise, you can only discuss what is and what isn't a line.

Comment: "4.Line with constant curvature that is equal from both sides": what ?

Comment: I usually use a ruler. :-)

Comment: @WolfgangKais: even in an hyperbolic space ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Well, usually, I don't make drawings in hyperbolic spaces. I think that we can't distinguish between "straight" and "not straight" until we define what a "line" is.

Comment: @WolfgangKais: probably a kind of hyperbola.

Answer (score 1):

None of these definitions as satisfactory as they rely on other concepts, such as distance or curvature, even less defined.

Answer (score 1):

A line is straight(in plane or curved space) if the covariant derivative of the velocity curve along the tangent space of it is $0$, i.e. $\nabla_\dot\gamma\dot\gamma=0$. It can be thought as a geodesic.